# Why is this C++ code not compiling?

Tags: c++, gtk, header-files

I'm using GTK+ and for some reason my screen capture function is failing to compile with the error:

> main.cpp:17:97: error: ‘gdk_pixbuf_get_from_drawable’ was not declared in this scope

Which .H file is gdk_pixbuf_get_from_drawable declared in? Here is the code below:

```
#include <libCrossLibs.h>
#include <gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf.h>
#include <gdk/gdk.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

ILibraryInstance* inst;

GdkPixbuf* get_screenshot() {
    GdkPixbuf* screenshot;
    GdkWindow* rootWindow;
    gint x_orig, y_orig;
    rootWindow = gdk_get_default_root_window();
    gint width, height;
    width = gdk_window_get_width(rootWindow);
    height = gdk_window_get_height(rootWindow);
    gdk_window_get_origin(rootWindow,&x_orig,&y_orig);

    screenshot =  gdk_pixbuf_get_from_drawable(NULL, rootWindow, 
        NULL, x_orig, y_orig, 0, 0, width, height);

    return screenshot;
}

int main(void) {
    inst = InitializeLibraries();
}
```

Comment: According to `gtk` documentation, the function `gdk_pixbuf_get_from_drawable` is defined in `gdk/gdk.h` (http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Pixbufs.html)

Comment: Which is already included in the project

Comment: This was a good question, it got closed unfortutantely, but i had the same problem and the acccepted solution below was also solution for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently gdk_pixbuf_get_from_drawable has been replaced with gdk_pixbuf_get_from_window. Source: [GNOME documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Pixbufs.html#gdk-pixbuf-get-from-window)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't think the function `gdk_pixbuf_get_from_drawable` exists. Either you misspelled it, you're missing an `#include`, or your platform does not provide that function.

Comment: I know I must be missing an include, the question is which include is it in? The docs say it should be in gdk.h, but it's obviously not there.

Comment: try searching through the gdk header files manually